# Should we create a singleton of of web service client @WebServiceClient

Tags: java, soap

My application needs to invoke a SOAP service and is a multithreaded application. 
I have generated web service client using cxf-codegen-plugin. Now if invoke the SOAP service using the generated client as 
        `new AddWSService().getAddWS().add(x,y);` 
 Does it hurt performance creating a new Client always? Should I need to consider caching the client instance?

Comment: Premature optimization is a bad thing. Dependency Injection is a good thing.

Comment: I agree 100%. But if try to @Autowire AddWSService stub it would not work. How do I inject the client stub in my code?

Comment: Is different question, perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888501/how-to-use-spring-autowired-in-a-custom-cxf-interceptor is of help?

Comment: Hum. Wrong link. Cannot find the one I mean.

Comment: anyways I think I got it @WebServiceRef (AddWSService.class) private AddWS;